# Count documents by ignoring duplicates in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Each appointment has some services. I want to find total count of appointments for each service.

My document looks like this:

```
[{
  "appointmentTag":"xyz",
  "services" : [
    {
      "name" : "service1",
      "estimatedTime":20
    },
    {
      "name" : "service2",
      "estimatedTime":40
    }
  ]
},
{
  "appointmentTag":"abc",
  "services" : [
    {
      "name" : "service2",
      "estimatedTime":100
    },
    {
      "name" : "service2",
      "estimatedTime":30
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output is as following:

```
{"serviceName":"service1", "count":1}
{"serviceName":"service2", "count":2}
```

The query that i tried:

```
db.appointments.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$services"},
    {"$group": {
        "_id": "$services.name",
        "count": {"$sum":1}
    }}
]);
```

Getting following results:

```
{"serviceName":"service1", "count":1}
{"serviceName":"service2", "count":3}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it almost correct. After unwinding, when you group by serviceName, instead of counting, use $addToSet of appointmentTag and then count that array. Something like this:

```
   db.test.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$services"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$services.name",
      "appointments": {
        "$addToSet": "$appointmentTag"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "ServiceName": "$_id","_id":0,
      "countOfAppointments": {
        "$size": "$appointments"
      }
    }
  }
])
```